# SQL Server treating non unique fields with Unicode characters as duplicates while they aren't duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, indexing, unique-index

SQL Server is treating the following characters as same though they are different Unicode characters. When I place a unique non clustered index on the column holding these characters SQL Server doesn't let me (throwing an errors saying there are duplicate keys, while they are not duplicate). I am already using nvarchar to support Unicode characters.

The Default collation being `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (I need to support Persian / Arabic characters along with all Latin / Indian / Chinese / Japanese characters (Unicode))

```
// Some characters are unseen so please copy and paste the whole
// code area in a Unicode supported text editor.
ٔ
ؐ
ۡ
ۚ
ٝ
ﷲ
۠
ݐ
ݘ
ۖ
ۻ
ݝ
ݡ
ۗ
ﮎ
ػ
ﮒ
ﮪ
ݻ
```

---

Following is the SQL Server CREATE statement without unique indexing (had to disable unique indexing on `TheWord` field since, as mentioned above, SQL Server is treating all the above characters as the same character (or may be I am missing something here?)).

```
CREATE TABLE [peplamb].[Words](
    [WordId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TheWord] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [SourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Words] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WordId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Am I missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you expect a Latin1 collation to correctly sort non-Latin1 characters?

Comment: hey @eggyal thanks for the quick reply, I am not really looking for any sort behavior but a unique non clustered index on `TheWord` field that supports Unicode characters.

Comment: Textual comparisons (required for detecting uniqueness) are only meaningful in the context of an ordering, which is what a collation is.

Comment: @eggyal thanks again, I am not concerned about the order as long as the Unicode is supported, which in this case nvarchar enables Unicode character support. Which collection in your opinion would you suggest in order to make the textual comparison between the above characters in `TheWord` column to be considered as unique individuals rather then them all being considered as a single character (which is the current behavior with the above mentioned collection) ? Thank you again for your time in looking into this!!!

Comment: The point is that the same characters may be treated differently depending on the language in which the text is written, so no single collation (short perhaps of a mere binary one) can suffice for text in arbitrary languages.

Comment: hmm I understand, but its wired, in MySQL when you select UTF-8 collation it does all the magic no matter what the language is (well thats the idea behind UTF-8 / UTF-16 to support multiple languages) so do you mean I will need to create individual tables with individual collation selected based on individual language? ( which in MySQL can all be done in a single table)